# Calculating Distinct Scores in an Exam with Variable Parameters (N and X)

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Following is the question that was asked in ZIO 2023 as the first question.

There is an exam with N problems. For each problem, a participant can either choose
to answer the problem, or skip the problem. If the participant chooses to answer the
problem and gets it correct, the participant is awarded X points. If the participant
chooses to answer the problem but answers it incorrectly, 1 point is deducted from
their score. If the participant skipped the problem, there is no change to their score.
For each of the following values of N and X, compute the number of distinct scores
the participant could obtain in the exam:

(a) N = 7, X = 4

(b) N = 15, X = 18

(c) N = 30, X = 20

Following is my approach to solve the question:

[image]

So these are total 15 cases, as bubbled in the figure where c stands for correct, w for wrong and s for skipped.

[image]

These are the cases where there are three of them possible: as shown in the figure 5c, 1w, 1s is one way the student can attempt the paper likewise 4c, 1w, 2s and 4c, 2w, 1s are two more ways to attempt the paper.

Therefore adding the 15 cases in the first image and the next 15 in the second one we get a total of 30 cases -which is the solution given to the problem in the answer key. However, there can be 6 more cases:
6w, 1s

5w, 2s

4w, 3s

3w, 4s

2w, 5s

1w, 6s

Am I calculating something wrong? Is this the correct way to solve questions like these? I think these questions are of combinatorics. I am a student who is not familiar with combinatorics. Is there a specific approach or formula that needs to be used when solving such questions? Any resources would be helpful!!

Comment: For the first, if there are $0$ attempts, the score is $0$.  If there is exactly $1$, the score is one of $-1, X$.  If there are exactly $k$ attempts the score is one of $\{i\times X-(k-i)\}_{i=0}^k$.  Phrased differently,  the possible scores are $\{aX-b\}_{a,b≥0\,a+b≤n}$

Comment: Your not counting the distincts scores. But you are counting the distincts corrections. For example 5 wrong + 2 success scores 3.while 1 success + 1 wrong + 5skipped scores also 3. So differents corrections can have same score.